# C++ version of process.stdin.on from Nodejs

Tags: c++, terminal, stdin

I would like to know how to catch keypress in `c++` from terminal. Back in `nodejs` I would do:

```js
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.on(code => [...stuff]);
```

Now how would I do that in `c++`.

**Rules:**

- It has to not block the main thead *(if posible)*.
- It has to work with soft keyboard *(e.g. mobile device's keyboard)*.
- It has to catch every keypress *(including Ctrl, Alt, Shift, Arrow keys and **Ctrl-C**)*

Comment: This very much depends on the OS. If you don't want to block the main thread, how will you check for input? [This dup](/questions/2654504/trying-to-read-keyboard-input-without-blocking-windows-c) shows one option for Windows. A more cross-platform approach is ncurses in a second thread and writing the resulting keycodes into a pipe with a non-blocking read endpoint.

Comment: Using plain and standard C++ you can't detect key-presses. You need to use functions related to the operating system to work directly with the terminal.